# What symbol should I use to indicate the 'cell above' in a formula that applies to a list with multiple values and blank cells I need to fill?

Tags: excel, formula, cell, fill

This formula below is what I need but entering an 'up' arrow does not work. When I do copy and paste an 'up' arrow (as typing 'up' only moves my curser back one) it creates the #NAME? error. Which symbol should I use in the formula to refer to the cell above?

Select column A
hit F5 to open the "Go To" dialog. enter image description here
click “Special…”
tick “Blanks” and click “OK”

enter an equals sign, =
hit the up arrow key, ↑
hold down Ctrl and hit Enter
Now all the previously empty cells have a formula that references the cell above.

To replace the formulas with the values, copy column A and paste over itself with “Paste Special” → “Values”.

Note: If the F5 key does not open the "Go To" dialogue, the function keys on a laptop may use the laptop controls as a default. In that case, hold the Fn key while pressing F5.

Comment: Just try leaving out the up arrow bit - you can just type the address of the first cell you want referenced.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.